# Unable to create kafka connector using REST API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run Kafka workers in distributed mode. Unlike standalone mode, we cannot pass the connector property file while starting the worker in distributed mode. In Distributed mode, workers are started separately and we deploy and manage the connectors on those workers using REST API

Reference Link - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html#connect-managing-distributed-mode

I tried building a connector by passing the below values in curl command and execued it

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"sailpointdb","connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","tasks.max":"1","connection.password " : " abc","connection.url " : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","connection.user " : "abc" ,"query" : " SELECT * FROM (SELECT NAME, FROM_UNIXTIME(completed/1000) AS 
TASKFAILEDON FROM abc WHERE COMPLETION_STATUS = 'Error') as A","mode" : " timestamp","timestamp.column.name" : "TASKFAILEDON","topic.prefix" : "dbevents","validate.non.null" : "false" }}' http://localhost:8089/connectors/
```

I am getting below error - curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Please let me know what is wrong with the above curl statement, am i missing anything here

Answer (score 1):

1. You had an extra closing curly brace in your JSON which won't help
2. If you're `POST`ing to `/connectors` you need the `name` and `config` root level elements. But, I recommend using `PUT` `/config` because you can re-run it to update the config if you need to

Try this:

```
curl -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
      http://localhost:8089/connectors/source-jdbc-sailpointdb-00/config \
      -d '{
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.password ": " abc",
        "connection.url ": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db",
        "connection.user ": "abc",
        "query": " SELECT * FROM (SELECT NAME, FROM_UNIXTIME(completed/1000) AS TASKFAILEDON FROM abc WHERE COMPLETION_STATUS = 'Error') as A",
        "mode": " timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "TASKFAILEDON",
        "topic.prefix": "dbevents",
        "validate.non.null": "false"
    }'
```